# A new Nextjs web app gives sourceMap errors, how do I read the logs?

Tags: webpack, logging, next.js

So I've build a website following Next.js tutorial, [here](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app). And now I've started to add things and tweak a little.

All of a sudden, I get this very annoying nagger in the console saying:

```
next-dev.js?3515:20 Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
```

And now, I can't for the life of me remember what I've added that would generate this Warning. I've tried to comment out the latest component I added.

Oh, and yeah, I tried to add support for `react-i18next`, **so the real question** I need help with, is:

### How do I get good readable logs?

My biggest file is maximum 100 rows, so looking for errors at row `3515` doesn't really do me any good.

And the `sourceMaps` doesn't seem to be helpful either.

[image: Nextjs sourceMap issue]

My `next.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'sv'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
  },
  sassOptions: {
        includePaths: [
            path.join(__dirname, 'styles'),
            path.join(__dirname, 'components')
        ],
  },
}
```

Where should I start looking for errors?

### Edit:

```
import React from "react";
import cn from 'classnames';
import styles from './main-nav.module.scss';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';
import LangSwitcher from './lang-switcher';
import MenuItems from './menu-items';

export default class MainNav extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, children, type, state) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      children: children,
      type: type,
      show: false,
      expanded: true,
      locale: '',
    };
  }
  toggleMenu = () => {
    const currentState = this.state.expanded;
    this.setState({ expanded: !currentState });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={cn(styles["main-nav"])}>
          <div className={cn(styles["main-nav-inner"])}>
            <div className={cn(styles["capow-logo"])}>
              <h2>
                <Link href="/">
                  <Image
                    src='/images/Jorgeuos-logo.svg'
                    className={cn(styles["jorgeuos-logo"])}
                    width={160}
                    height={69}
                    alt='Jorgeuos'
                  />
                </Link>
              </h2>
            </div>
            <MenuItems
            expanded={this.state.expanded}
            styles={styles}
            toggleMenu={this.toggleMenu}
            ></MenuItems>
            {this.children}
          </div>
          <LangSwitcher></LangSwitcher>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm slowly getting the hang of this now. I can't use forwardRef inside of class component, so I need to break out my logo into it's own functional component I assume.

Comment: The error is somewhere inside the `MainNav` component. Do you have a `next/image` wrapped in a `next/link` anywhere in that component?

Comment: Yes, the logo, which should lead to home and in a language switcher. Why can't I have images inside of Link-tags?

Comment: Add an `<a>` element around the `Image` component (as a direct child to `Link`).

Comment: Ok, thanks! I fixed it now, gonna post my solution. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error message gave me some pointers, but still, the stack trace is somewhat complicated to follow. Surely I'm missing some config in my configs.
I've added `eslint` in `package.json` for now so I get an error while compiling.

So I got an aha moment reading the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-functional-component):

> If the child of `Link` is a functional component, in addition to using `passHref` and `legacyBehavior`, you must wrap the component in `React.forwardRef`:

My new`Logo` component:

```js
import React from "react";
import cn from 'classnames';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const LogoLink = React.forwardRef(({onClick, styles, href}, ref) => (
    <a
      ref={ref}
      href={href}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      <Image
        src='/images/Jorgeuos-logo.svg'
        className={cn(styles["jorgeuos-logo"])}
        width={160}
        height={69}
        alt='Jorgeuos'
      />
    </a>
));

function Logo(styles) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const link = router.locale === 'en' ? '' : 'sv';
  const ref = React.createRef();
    return (
      <div className={cn(styles[""])}>
        <Link
          ref={ref}
          href={link}
          passHref legacyBehavior
        >
          <LogoLink styles={styles}></LogoLink>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
}

export default Logo;
```

I still had some other errors confusing me, but after searching for every `Image` component wrapped in a `Link` component, I applied the same fix and the error is now gone.